# Get td text and send it to controller with jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to get the value of a `td` from the `table`. The table has a checkbox 
and my goal is to get these values and send them to the controller for insert all.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Archive</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
    <th>S.No.</th>
    <th>matricule</th>
    <th>nom & prenom</th>
    <th>salaire net</th>
    <th>nbre de jour </th>
    <th>prime</th>
  </tr>
  @if($salaries->count()) @foreach($salaries as $key => $salarie)
    <tr id="tr_{{$salarie->id}}">
      <td>archive</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="{{$salarie->id}}"></td>
      <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
      <td>{{ $salarie->matricule }}</td>
      <td>{{ $salarie->nom }} {{ $salarie->prenom }}</td>
      <td>{{ $salarie->salairenet }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="{{$data['nbr']}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach @endif
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

  $('.checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length) {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });

  $('.add-all').on('click', function(e) {
    var idsArr = [];
    $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      idsArr.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
    if (idsArr.length <= 0) {
      alert("Please select atleast one record to update.");
    } else {
      alert(idsArr);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: are you getting listing of selected ids array of not?

Comment: yet i get it but value of td not yet

Comment: which td value. I assuming that you need checkbox value. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the value a class. Then I get all the checked inputs. Then I get the sibling td that has that given class. Get this value and make the sum in the end.

```js
$('.table').on('click', function() {
  // Get all checked boxes
  var allChecked = $('.checkbox:checked');
  
  // Prepare the result
  var allValues = [];
  var allNames = [];
  
  // Loop every checkbox
  for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
    
    // Get the siblings td with class 'salaireValue'
    var currentValue = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.salaireValue')[0];
    var currentName = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.name')[0];
    
    // Push to arrays
    allValues.push(parseInt($(currentValue)[0].innerText))
    allNames.push($(currentName)[0].innerText)
    
  }

  console.log(allValues);
  console.log(allNames);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="salaireValue">1</td>
      <td class="name">John</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="salaireValue">2</td>
      <td class="name">Louise</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="salaireValue">5</td>
      <td class="name">Frank</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i dont want a sum value , i want just value checked

Comment: Sorry man, I don't fully understand. Do you want an array of all the values?

Comment: no, i want just array of salaireNet and array of NOM and PRENOM, in this exemple he give me a total of salaireNet ,i dont want a total i want just array of salaireNet

Comment: So in this example, the expected result is [1,2] [name1,name2] ?

Comment: No problem! Don't to forget to upvote and accept this answer :)